# Firebase RealTime Databse, No Returns?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

New to firebase databases here, trying it out for a login. (wanna use username's instead of emails)

So using a Realtime Database, But I can't seem to get anything out of the database.
I can't see anything wrong with what i'm doing. At first thought it was because of the Rules, same results after setting them to auth == null.

Any idea's?

```
 public FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://MyApp.firebaseio.com/");
 private readonly string ChildName = "Users";

 public async Task<List<Userlogin>> GetAllUser()
        {

         return (await firebase
                .Child(ChildName)
                .OnceAsync<Userlogin>()).Select(item =>
                new Userlogin
                {
                    user_login = item.Object.user_login,
                    passwords = item.Object.passwords
                }).ToList();
        }

  public async Task<Userlogin> GetUser(string user_login)
        {
            try
            {
                var allUsers = await GetAllUser();
                await firebase
                .Child(ChildName)
                .OnceAsync<Userlogin>();
                return allUsers.Where(a => a.user_login == user_login).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

private async void Login_Phase1()
{
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Usernamelabel.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password.Text))
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Email and Password", "OK");
                else
                {
                    var user = await GetUser(Usernamelabel.Text);

                    if (user != null)
                        if (Usernamelabel.Text == user.user_login && Password.Text == user.passwords)
                        {
                            Login_Phase2();
                        }
                        else
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Fail", "Please enter correct Email and Password", "OK");
                    else
                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Fail", "User not found", "OK");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
            }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

> This might not be the case always I believe

When Importing your Databse "Users" In my case if you import using a Json File.

For some odd reason I had to go create a Manual User on the database for it to register the other users on the Call.

Solution:

Just create a New Child on the Database With the correct properties.